# Is there something else replace to resource owner password grant flow in oauth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have first party app and client server and I want to implement authentication by using Resource Owner Password Grant Flow.

However, according to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-3.4 they told do not use those grant flow.

There seems no security issues with direct control application and service, Can't i use them?

And are there something else that can replace those grant flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my view, the main reason to avoid ROPC grant is because there are (more) chances for Phishing. A consumer may get fooled easily since you login screen is not 'that popular' like google or Facebook and they enter the credentials at wrong place, and your application is at risk.

If your application is not using browser, probably it is ok to use it (of course considering many other facts)

One of the many references  [here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications)